# Sorting randomly generated numbers from lowest to highest

Tags: c++

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned) time(0));
    int random_integer;
    int lowest =- 10, highest = 10;
    int range = (highest-lowest) + 1;
    for(int index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
        random_integer = lowest+int(range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));
        cout << random_integer << ' ';
    }

    cout << "\n=============== \n";
    system("pause"); 
}
```

How do I sort the numbers that computer will generate and line them up from lowest to highest and after that print out second highest number?
Thank you.

Comment: There's a `sort()` function.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like homework

Comment: You only need the 2nd largest or need to see the sorted result for all numbers?

Comment: What have you tried? Many sorting algorithms exist and example code can be found for them. For instance Bubblesort, MergeSort, HeapSort, etc can all sort the numbers. After that, printing the second highest is simply printing the second highest index of the sorted set.

Comment: @Song wang I need the result for all numbers

Comment: @AlexJohanson, How about some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: @AlexJohanson store all the generated numbers in a vector then call std::sort on the vector.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options - remember all generated numbers in a `std::vector`, then call `std::sort` on it and print the second number. This in both memory and time sub-optimal.

The second (and preferred) option is remembering the lowest two numbers in temporary variables and adjust them as you generate subsequent random numbers. (or using `std::partial_sort`, but that seems like overkill in this case).

Comment: The second option is smart but may not answer this question, depending on what "line them up" means.

Comment: @DrewDormann ah, that's true. Ok, the second only works if he needs all the numbers.

Comment: Along the lines of the first option, something like `std::multiset` can be used.

Comment: Thanks Luchian, but how do I achieve this? I mean what's the syntax for it? how do I remember the generated numbers and how do I call upon std::sort

Comment: @AlexJohanson did you try and search for `vector` and `sort` on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the number directly in the `for` loop, add the number to a [`std::vector<>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). Then you can call [`std::sort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) to sort the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `<algorithm>` to help you create your random numbers in a vector, and then simply sort the vector:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int myRandomFunction() {
   ...
}

/* Preallocate some space */
std::vector<int> values(100);
std::algorithm::generate(values.begin(), values.end(), myRandomFunction);
std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using `vector` and `sort()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int random_integer;
    int lowest=-10, highest=10;
    int range=(highest-lowest)+1;
    for(int index=0; index<20; index++){
        random_integer = lowest+int(range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));
        v.push_back(random_integer);
        //cout << random_integer << ' ';
    }
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    cout << endl << v[v.size()-2] << endl;

    cout<<"\n=============== \n";
    system("pause"); 
}
```

This just prints the second highest number:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int random_integer;
    int lowest=-10, highest=10;
    int a=lowest,b=lowest;
    int range=(highest-lowest)+1;
    for(int index=0; index<20; index++){
        random_integer = lowest+int(range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));
        cout << random_integer << ' ';
        if(a<random_integer) 
        {
            a=random_integer;
            continue;
        }
        if(b<random_integer) 
        {
            b=random_integer;
            continue;
        }
        //cout << random_integer << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl << min(a,b) << endl;

    cout<<"\n=============== \n";
    system("pause"); 
}
```

Comment: It does not sort numbers from lowest to highest